# Segmentation fault (core dumped) AIDE --init return code 139

Tags: security

Ubuntu 20.10

I get the following when I run aideinit

```
sudo aideinit
Overwrite existing /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new [Yn]? 
Running aide --init...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
AIDE --init return code 139
```

Comment: Are you running `aideinit` as `root` (via `sudo`)? With `--verbose`?

Comment: yes, as root but no verbose

Comment: there's a bug report for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aide/+bug/1903298 - no fix tho

Answer (score 1):

I can tell what I did to mitigate this bug, and It's worked for me (do it as power user or root):

1. Completely purge installed AIDE:

   ```
   apt purge aide aide-common
   rm -rf /var/log/aide
   ```
2. Install AIDE back again:

   ```
   apt update
   apt install aide-common aide-dynamic
   ```
3. Then rebuild config:

   ```
   update-aide.conf
   cp -v /var/lib/aide/aide.conf.autogenerated /etc/aide/aide.conf
   ```
4. Run the init script:

   ```
   aideinit -f
   ```

Then, for me, there were no errors, and AIDE was running well.

Comment: thanks Consta but since then I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute and no issues.

Comment: How did you know this is a bug?